# Problems with fcvDrawContouru8 for 64bit systems

Tags: c++, computer-vision

I am using fastcv v1.7 to develop an image processing algorithm, a part of the process includes finding contours from an image, selecting a choice few contours among them and then drawing those contours only.

This code block runs smoothly in 32bit systems producing expected output but while on 64bit systems same code crashes unexpectedly during the loop which executes fcvDrawContouru8. The crash is unexpected as sometimes loop iterataes 2 or 3 times and sometimes crashes on first iteration. Can't seem to work out if the problem is with memory allocation in 64bit or with fastcv itself. Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
    uint8_t* dist_fcv = (uint8_t*)fcvMemAlloc(dist_8u.cols*dist_8u.rows*OPT_CV_ELEM_SIZE(OPT_CV_8UC1), FCV_ALIGN);
    memset(dist_fcv, 0, dist_8u.cols*dist_8u.rows*OPT_CV_ELEM_SIZE(OPT_CV_8UC1));

    uint32_t maxNumContours = MAX_CNT;
    uint32_t sizeOfpBuffer = 0;
    uint32_t maxPoints= ((2*dist_8u.cols) + (2 * dist_8u.rows));
    uint32_t  pNumContours = 0;
    uint32_t pNumContourPoints[MAX_CNT] = {0};
    uint32_t** pContourStartPointsfind = (uint32_t**)fcvMemAlloc(MAX_CNT*2*sizeof(uint32_t*),16);
    sizeOfpBuffer = (MAX_CNT * 2 * maxPoints * sizeof(uint32_t));
    uint32_t *pPointBuffer=(uint32_t *)malloc(sizeOfpBuffer);
    memset(pPointBuffer,0,sizeOfpBuffer);
    int32_t hierarchy[MAX_CNT][4];
    void* cHandle = fcvFindContoursAllocate(dist_8u.cols);

    fcvFindContoursExternalu8(textureless.data.ptr,
            dist_8u.cols,
            dist_8u.rows,
            dist_8u.cols,
            maxNumContours,
            &pNumContours,
            pNumContourPoints,
            pContourStartPointsfind,
            pPointBuffer,
            sizeOfpBuffer,
            hierarchy,
            cHandle);

    size_t n_TL = 0;

    uint32_t** pContourStartPointsdraw = (uint32_t**)fcvMemAlloc(MAX_CNT*2*sizeof(uint32_t*),16);
    uint32_t pNumDrawContourPoints[MAX_CNT] = {0};
    uint32_t* dPointBuffer=(uint32_t *)malloc(sizeOfpBuffer);
    uint32_t* start_contour = pPointBuffer;
    uint32_t* start_contour_dPoint = dPointBuffer;

    uint32_t** startFind_ptr = pContourStartPointsfind;
    uint32_t** draw_ptr = pContourStartPointsdraw;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < pNumContours; i++,startFind_ptr++)
    {

        int points_per_contour = pNumContourPoints[i];
        double area = polyArea(start_contour,points_per_contour*2);

        if(area < min_textureless_area)
        {
            start_contour = start_contour + points_per_contour*2;
            continue;
        }

        *(draw_ptr) = *(startFind_ptr);
        pNumDrawContourPoints[n_TL] = pNumContourPoints[i];
        memcpy(start_contour_dPoint,start_contour,points_per_contour*2*sizeof(uint32_t));
        start_contour_dPoint = start_contour_dPoint + points_per_contour*2;
        start_contour = start_contour + points_per_contour*2;
        n_TL++;
        draw_ptr++;


    }

    uint32_t* holeflag = (uint32_t*)malloc(pNumContours*sizeof(uint32_t));
    memset(holeflag,0,pNumContours*sizeof(uint32_t));
    uint32_t bufferSize = 0;

    start_contour_dPoint = dPointBuffer;

    draw_ptr = pContourStartPointsdraw;

    for(int i = 0; i < n_TL; i++)
    {
        int points_per_contour = pNumDrawContourPoints[i];
        bufferSize = points_per_contour*2*sizeof(uint32_t);

            fcvDrawContouru8(dist_fcv,
                        dist_8u.cols,
                        dist_8u.rows,
                        dist_8u.cols,
                        1,
                        holeflag,
                        &pNumDrawContourPoints[i],
                        (const uint32_t ** __restrict)(draw_ptr),
                        bufferSize,
                        start_contour_dPoint,
                        hierarchy,
                        1,1,i+1,0)

        start_contour_dPoint = start_contour_dPoint + points_per_contour*2;
        draw_ptr++;


    }

    free(pPointBuffer);
    fcvFindContoursDelete(cHandle);
    fcvMemFree(pContourStartPointsfind);
```